# WiFi and bluetooth don't function on Asus Vivobook 15 in Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: wireless, mediatek

I just received a brand new Asus Vivobook 15 and installed Ubuntu 23.04 on it. I noticed that the wifi connection wasn't available in the "Try Ubuntu" USB-mounted OS, but proceeded to install Ubuntu 23.04 anyway, checking the box for installing third-party drivers. I ran `lshw -C network` with the following output:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:ff0-fef memory:fff0300000-fff03fffff memory:fcf00000-fcf07fff
```

The output for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net` is:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:7902]
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:5520]
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Micron Technology Inc Device [1344:5413] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Micron Technology Inc Device [1344:2100]
```

After installation, there is no wifi device available. I have searched for solutions, but I have only come across an old thread about Mediatek wifi devices not working on Ubuntu 20.04 and recommending updating to kernel 5.12+ and Ubuntu 21.04.

Another set of [instructions](https://itsfoss.com/fix-no-wireless-network-ubuntu/) recommend connecting over ethernet (which I don't have) or bluetooth tethering (I also cannot turn on bluetooth on the laptap). The last ditch effort is to mount the Ubuntu ISO as a cdrom, but that was also not detected by the Software Sources application.

Does anyone have any idea whether Mediatek devices function on the newest Ubuntu kernels, or should I return the laptop to the seller?

**Edit: As of May 13, 2023, the Mediatek MTK7902 wifi/bluetooth card is not supported in Linux 6.3 kernel.**

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`

Comment: OK, I added it.

Comment: What is the laptop model number?

Comment: It doesn't seem that the mediatek mtk7902 devices are supported in the kernel yet

Comment: I am facing same issue with my asus vivobook 16 with same wifi. Were you able to make it work? Is there an issue i can follow to get  updates?

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time trying to find a solution for this.

July 21: It seems the card is not supported: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=3ad05eed61

But someone from another site shared this repo: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/usb/musb/mediatek.c

I contacted the emails but no one replied. seems for the USB though not for the card.

So last resort was external USB-WIFI, I tried Elecon USB-WIFI WTC117 but it does not work, so I purchased TP-Link USB Wifi TL-WN725N and it works well for now. Someone from reddit used BrosTrend AC1200 adapter and it works well for them!

I hope some can help in integrating this card because now with wifi-usb we can connect but the Bluetooth is not working.

Best of luck!

Update Aug 6: replacing the wifi_card is also an option, but it would void the warranty, check your laptops architecture first before buying a card. I have purchased Intel AX210NGW and downloaded the drivers from [intel website](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/204836/intel-wifi-6e-ax210-gig/downloads.html), installed them on Windows, and it works perfectly. for Ubuntu the 6.2 and 5.19 work fine from what I tried, both Bluetooth and wifi.

Answer (score 0):

I have exact same problem.

Workarround:

If you have an **Android** with a **mobile internet connection** *(beware of possible high billings depending on the active plan with mobile phone company)*, connect USB cable, enable **USB tethering** option and there you go. You should have internet access.