# Wifi not showing in Asus Vivobook 1605VA

Tags: drivers, wireless, 23.04

I bought a new asus vivobook 1605VA and formatted it to install ubuntu 23.04
But now the Wireless is not working on the laptop, I tried a lot of things like installing the RTL drivers from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/installing-realtek-rtl8821ce-driver-to-use-the-wireless-network-interface-in-ubuntu/amp/) but its still not showing any improvements.

This is my network settings, wireless is not showing, and currently I am using internet by tethering to my mobile.[image]

Image contains some of the output, if you need any other output please let me know..

[image]

Comment: The Mediatek 7902 is your wireless card and I regret that there is, so far, no linux driver. please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1467679/wifi-and-bluetooth-dont-function-on-asus-vivobook-15-in-ubuntu-23-04

Comment: Thanks man, I reached the same conclusion after a month long search. Switched to Windows for now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the airplane mode is not enabled?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0uB_PDtQRw

If the wifi adapter disabled on the hardware the linux will not shows any adapter.

FN + F2 : I think on ASUS, but check it on the ASUS website.

Comment: No airplane mode is not enabled I double-checked.

Comment: Enable Wi-Fi in the BIOS

Comment: that also I already did, Wireless networking is enabled in BIOS.

Comment: maybe check if you have additional device updates?

Comment: maybe you have Broadcom device https://linuxhint.com/ubuntu-no-wi-fi-adapter-found-issue/

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Turn on your Asus Netbook. If your netbook is already on, click the "Start" button, click the arrow next to the "Shut Down" button and then click "Restart."
2. Wait for the Asus Netbook BIOS screen to appear, then press the "F2" key.
3. Press the "Right" arrow to scroll over to the "Advanced" tab.
4. Press the "Down" arrow until you reach the "Onboard Devices Configuration" option. Press the "Enter" key.
5. Press the "Down" arrow to "Onboard WLAN" then press the "Enter" key.
6. If the "Disabled" option is highlighted, press the "Up" arrow to highlight the "Enabled" option, then press the "Enter" key.
7.Press the "F10" key. Press the "Enter" key to save your changes and exit the BIOS.
```