# Wifi drivers for ASUS PRO A620

Tags: drivers, wireless

My pc does not detect wifi networks. After a fresh install of Linux Ubuntu on a new machine, the computer is not able to detect any wifi networks. I checked the manufacturer's website for wifi drivers, but they are only available for Windows.

My setup is dual-boot. It has two solid state disks ADATA SSD 512GB LEGEND 840 M.2 PCIE M.2 2280. Windows 11 is installed on the first disk and Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.3 LTS on the other. The motherboard is ASUS TUF GAMING A620-PRO WIFI. The wifi adapter name is MediaTek Wi-Fi 6 MT7902LEN Wireless LAN Card. Ubuntu kernel is 6.2.0.26-generic.

Ubuntu seems to be able to recognize the device. When I run `sudo lshw -C network` I get:

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: enp5s0
       version: 05
       serial: 08:bf:b8:72:53:ea
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.2.0-26-generic firmware=rtl8125b-2_0.0.2 07/13/20 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:33 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fc800000-fc80ffff memory:fc810000-fc813fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fc400000-fc4fffff memory:fc500000-fc507fff
```

The adapter name was found using the command `lspci -knn | grep 0280`:

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:7902]
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:6040]
```

but also from the control panel of Windows.

The detailed ubuntu kernel is found using `uname -a`:

```
Linux Linux 6.2.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Jul 13 16:27:29 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Unfortunately that device isn't supported yet in Linux

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1467679/wifi-and-bluetooth-dont-function-on-asus-vivobook-15-in-ubuntu-23-04 "Edit: As of May 13, 2023, the Mediatek MTK7902 wifi/bluetooth card is not supported in Linux 6.3 kernel."

Answer (score 1):

The adapter MediaTek Wi-Fi 6 MT7902LEN is not supported by linux ([WiFi and bluetooth don't function on Asus Vivobook 15 in Ubuntu 23.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1467679/wifi-and-bluetooth-dont-function-on-asus-vivobook-15-in-ubuntu-23-04)).

To solve the problem I bought the TP-Link TX50E network card.