# MediaTek Corp. WiFi adapter is not recognized by Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: wireless, 23.10, adapter, mediatek

I bought laptop few days ago and decided to try Ubuntu, after installing my wifi was not working.

My Asus Vivobook S15 (Intel I5 13th Gen) is running Ubuntu 23.10, My Kernel Version is 6.7.2-060702-generic.

after running `sudo lshw -C network` -

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Network controller
   product: MEDIATEK Corp.
   vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: iomemory:600-5ff memory:6000000000-60000fffff memory:84000000-84007fff
```

I ran wireless-info script from https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info and this is the resulted txt file (I Was Using TP_Link USB Adapter for internet connection) --> https://pastebin.com/rhnW6tp3

how can I "Claim" this adapter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Sadly that Mediachip does not have a driver yet: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Atorvalds%2Flinux%20path%3A%2F%5Edrivers%5C%2Fnet%5C%2Fwireless%5C%2Fmediatek%5C%2F%2F%200x7902&type=code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No WIFI Adapter Found - ASUS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1386578/no-wifi-adapter-found-asus)

Comment: @moo That is Realtek. This is Mediatek.

Comment: There is currently no support for your 14c3:7902 device: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1467679/wifi-and-bluetooth-dont-function-on-asus-vivobook-15-in-ubuntu-23-04 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: You should get a USB WiFi card, until your current one is supported.